# Tensorflow: HTTP 403 Error when installing `tensorflow-deps`

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

I am trying to install tensorflow on a MacBook Air M1 by following the instructions on: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ in a virtual env `mlp`.

- `which python` outputs `/Users/bernardino/miniforge3/envs/mlp/bin/python\`
- When I run `conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps` I get the following error systematically.

```
Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
tensorflow-deps-2.9. | 3 KB      |                                       |   0%

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/apple/osx-arm64/tensorflow-deps-2.9.0-0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: 00:00.228593
CF-RAY: 72dbc1f67c2a5a1f-MXP

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Having the same issue on an Apple MacBook Pro M1 using miniforge and python3.9.12

Comment: @WaleedAlfaris let me know if you find a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I found another thread on the same issue on github https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11638
. From what they said, it seems anaconda packages cant be installed right now due to some outages. Heres the Tweet

https://twitter.com/condaproject/status/1549778710219444225

> @condaproject - 8:30 AM PST, July 20, 2022
>
> Some package downloads from http://conda.anaconda.org are currently being affected. The @anacondainc team has traced it back to Cloudflare's system outages and is actively working to resolve it. In the interim, please check https://cloudflarestatus.com for Cloudflare updates.